# ascii value as string to character in java

Tags: java, string, type-conversion, ascii

I have a String value `"\u0004"`

I need to convert it to character `'\u0004'`

I need to store this character back to the string.

How can this be done?

Comment: Do you understand what `\u0004` means? What exactly is the output supposed to be? `char c = 4`?

Comment: That's not a problem, though of course that's a non-printing character. You can append it

Comment: Do you mean you've got a string that consists of a backslash, then a u, then three zeroes then a four... or that you've got a string that was assigned via a Java string literal of `"\u0004"`? Those are very different situations. A [mcve] would make this a lot clearer.

Comment: `str.charAt(0)` will give you the character, then you can do whatever you want with it.

Comment: @luk2302 str.charAt(0) gives me u. \u0004 is ascii for control character EOT

Comment: @JonSkeet I am getting this value submitted through a form. So what I receive is "\u0004"

Comment: It's still not entirely clear to me. (For example, a debugger might be showing you the string as "\u0004" despite it being a single character.) If you have that string, and log its length, what does it show? Again, a [mcve] would help.

Comment: Do you have `String s = "\u0004";` or do you have `String s = "\\u0004";`? And what exactly do you want the final output to be? Maybe try explaining with an actually printable character instead such that the output can be more meaningful.

Comment: Note that if `str.charAt(0)` gives you `'u'`, then it *isn't* `"\u0004"` as otherwise `str.charAt(0)` would give you a backslash...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is answer you want

```
// string value that has "\" in front
String s = "\\u0004";

// substring to leave "\u" out
char c = (char)Integer.parseInt(s.substring(2));
```

Comment: You'd probably want to parse as hex though...